# (DirectX 11) Can a single vertex buffer be bound to more than one IA input slot at a time?

Tags: c++, directx-11, direct3d11

If I have different data types (position, normal and color, for example) that are not interleaved but are stored in the same vertex buffer, could I bind that buffer to more than one input slot in the IA stage to point to all 3 of these data areas simultaneously?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you have your data laid out and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is totally allowed.

When you call [IaSetVertexBuffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567392(v=vs.85).aspx)

you can provide the pOffsets parameter, which is the starting location within your buffer.

So it is possible to assign the same buffer in different slots with a different start location.